# ¿Como mejorar velocidad de transmision de imagen por TCP?

Tags: c#, tcpudp

estoy tratando de transmitir imagenes desde el host a un cliente y el cliente envia inputs al host (tipo any desk, la imagen se envia por TCP y los inputs por UDP) pero transmitir la imagen por TCP es muy lento y necesito que la imagen llegue de manera rapida, esto es lo que he intentado con TCP

Esta es la configuracion de los sockets:

```
 //cliente
_TCPClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        _TCPClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        _TCPClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
//host
_Server = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress, _Port));
        _Server.AllowNatTraversal(true);
        _Server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        _Server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

Clase Host

```
//Esto corre por medio de un hilo
private void SendImage()
{
    while (Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = Desktop.TakeScreenShoot();
            Desktop.SerializeScreen(_NetStream,bitmap);
        }
        catch
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Clase DeskTop

```
public static void SerializeScreen(Stream stream, Bitmap Image)
{
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    Image.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    int numBytes = (int)memory.Length;
    BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    binaryWriter.Write(numBytes);
    binaryWriter.Write(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, numBytes);
}

public static Image DeserializeScreen(Stream stream)
{
    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    int numBytes = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
    byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(numBytes);
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    return Image.FromStream(memory);
}
```

Clase cliente

```
private void ReciveMessageAsync()
{
    while (Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
    {
        ReciveMessage();
        
    }
}
protected override void ReciveMessage()
{
    try
    {
    //Esto es un evento que se activa al leer la imagen que recibe del host para mostrarlo en el picturebox            
    
    ImageRecibed?.Invoke(Desktop.DeserializeScreen(_NetStream));
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        _NetStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

[Aqui les dejo una demostracion del programa y su velocidad](https://youtu.be/QwC-IUb7t30) PD. el raton en el host se mueve rapido, esta se manda por UDP, lo que tarda es la imagen en llegar

Comment: ¿Banda ancha del router? ¿Velocidad de transmisión de los cables/WiFi?

Comment: MTU size? Configuración de la interfaz de red? Velocidad en los equipos de red intermedios (switches, routers)? Antivirus en el OS destino? Saber la causa de la velocidad baja (comparada con la esperada) requiere hacer un diagnóstico amplio del entorno completo

Comment: mi conexion es por VPN protocolo pptp, por wifi, mi velocidad de subida es de 8.8 Mbps y de bajada es de 24 Mbps

Comment: Estás condicionado por el servidor VPN, estás traduciendo cada petición para _meterte_ en el segmento de red interno de la VPN.

Comment: @Alfabravo que me recomiendas para mejorar la conexion???

Comment: @Alfabravo pense en transmitir todo por UDP pero tendria que cortar la imagen ya que supera el tamaño default del datagrama

Comment: Creo que no podrás hacer algo al respecto a menos que eches mano del servidor VPN y realices alguna configuración ahí.